# Prove that if $p\le n$, then $p$ does not divide $n! + 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

I'm having trouble on how to approach this problem

Prove that if $p\le n$, then $p$ does not divide $n! + 1$ ($p$ is prime and $n$ is an integer).

Comment: its trivial, $p$ divides $n!$, so it can't divide $n!+1$ at the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p$ divides $n!$. So it cannot divide $n!+1$.